# Chrome developer tools not visible

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

Screen shot of the whole window has been posted.The developer tools [appear as if it has been cut off

Comment: moderators ... is this question not clear ??

Comment: Does the console appear when you press the escape key ? Are there resize handles above the area you highlighted ? Try pressing F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I to open/close. Can you post a screenshot of whole window ?

Comment: pressing f12 or  Ctrl+Shift+I doesnot help

Comment: I mean a screenshot of the whole browser window, not the stack overflow page !

Comment: the case is same on all pages.. i will post the screenshot of the whole bowser window

Comment: Is there a resize mouse cursor when you hover over the blue highlighted html element ? (above the rendering/emulation buttons)

Also, try clicking the console tab and pressing escape to see if it opens up.

Comment: nope no change :( resizing handles are not visible either

Comment: Go to Gmail. open a chat. click on pop out window to open the chat in another window. inspect element. What happens?

Comment: wow..that opens up a proper developer tools window